# iphone - can presentModalViewController do it not fullscreen?

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller and I am presenting it modal, as in...

```
UIViewController *myWindow = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 115.0f, 120.0f);
myWindow.view.frame = myFrame;

[self presentModalViewController:myWindow animated:YES];
```

is there any way I can present it not full screen in a specific size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'standard' way to do this.

I have faked it by using a `UIActionSheet` and setting the view controller's view to as a subview of the actionsheet, and then resetting the bounds of the actionsheet. This is a pretty odd hack and I wouldn't recommend it.

```
sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

UIViewController *modalController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil];

sheet.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
[sheet addSubview:modalController.view];
[sheet showInView:self.view];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[sheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 728)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The obvious drawbacks here are the normal view controller events aren't triggered (`viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Not easily but you can make it *seem* smaller :)

Just make the root IUView in your xib full screen but with a clear transparent background. Then, inside that make your 'real' UI objects any size you want.

Comment: From what I've seen, when the modal presentation is completed, the view behind is unloaded, causing it to go black

Comment: Ah yes, it might do that. Blast. Oh well, looks like your way is the only way!